# Obtener acceso a los logs de prevista del tema de wordpress desplegado por bitnami en una VM GCP

Tags: wordpress, permisos, google-cloud-platform, ram, bitnami

Quería desplegar [este tema de wordpress](https://themeforest.net/item/luwix-data-science-analytics-wordpress-theme/37568282) en una máquina virtual de GCP, utilizando bitnami y la capa gratuita, siguiendo [este tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3Xq2tBCvhiU). Soy capaz de desplegar un tema por defecto pero, desafortunadamente, cuando subo el mío y hago clic en *Previsualización en vivo* obtengo el siguiente mensaje:

> There has been a critical error on this website. Please check your
> site admin email inbox for instructions.
>
> Learn more about troubleshooting WordPress.

Lo primero que pensé al buscar en Internet fue que mi máquina no tenía suficiente memoria RAM como se explica en [este post del foro](https://community.bitnami.com/t/there-has-been-a-critical-error-on-this-website-error-message-appears-when-trying-to-log-in/92687/4):

Así que intenté abrir los registros con SSH en la máquina virtual GCP pero la VM parece estar vacía.

```
officialdataguild@cloudshell:~ (the-data-guild-website)$ gcloud compute ssh wordpress-website-vm --project=the-data-guild-website
Did you mean zone [europe-west1-c] for instance: [wordpress-website-vm] (Y/n)?  n

No zone specified. Using zone [us-east1-b] for instance: [wordpress-website-vm].
Updating project ssh metadata...working.Updated [https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/the-data-guild-website].
Updating project ssh metadata...done.
Waiting for SSH key to propagate.
Warning: Permanently added 'compute.2745993064748503787' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
Linux wordpress-website-vm 4.19.0-20-cloud-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.19.235-1 (2022-03-17) x86_64

The programs included with the Debian GNU/Linux system are free software;
the exact distribution terms for each program are described in the
officialdataguild@wordpress-website-vm:~$ ls
officialdataguild@wordpress-website-vm:~$
```

Siguiendo [este tutorial sobre la visualización y el examen de los registros](https://help.dreamhost.com/hc/en-us/articles/216512217-Viewing-and-examining-your-error-log-via-SSH) busqué la carpeta correcta pero no fui capaz de encontrarla:

```
officialdataguild@wordpress-website-vm:~$ cd ~/logs
-bash: cd: /home/officialdataguild/logs: No such file or directory
```

Entonces, siguiendo este [guido para troubleshoot preblemas con wordpress desplegado con bitnami](https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/how-to/troubleshoot-wordpress-issues/) me fue un carpeta por debajo y hicé:

```
officialdataguild@wordpress-website-vm:~$ cd ..
officialdataguild@wordpress-website-vm:/home$ ls
bitnami  officialdataguild
officialdataguild@wordpress-website-vm:/home$ cd bitnami/
officialdataguild@wordpress-website-vm:/home/bitnami$ ls
bitnami_credentials  htdocs  stack

officialdataguild@wordpress-website-vm:/home/bitnami$ test ! -f "/opt/bitnami/common/bin/openssl" && echo "Approach A: Using system packages." || echo "Approach B: Self-contained installation."
Approach A: Using system packages.
officialdataguild@wordpress-website-vm:/home/bitnami$ sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh status
apache already running
mariadb already running
php-fpm already running
```

Comment: posiblemente todo este bien en la instalación inicial, lo mas seguro es que sea la copia la que este rota, suele ser algo normal en All In One, prueba a hacer la importación del backup en un localhost para ver si el problema persiste, si es asi intenta con otro plugin o una migración manual.

Comment: Muchas gracias para su comentario @JefferzonBol Intenté en el localhost y mi sitio funciona. El problema parece que sea en el cloud entonces ...

Answer (score 0):

El problema fue a causa del zip del theme que no contenia jetpack.php Entonces créé uno y luego me deshace del plugin.

Primero anadi una ssh en la maquina virtual donde hay wordpress:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No sé por qué pero esta llave era especial, tenía que cambiar algo al final para poder poner el nombre de usuario que quiero. No me recuerdo a donde fue para muestrar eso.

Luego hicé:

```
 C:\Users\antoi\.ssh> ssh -i .\gcp_priv.pem antoi@35.237.144.102
antoi@wordpress-website-vm:/opt/bitnami/apache/logs$ tail error_log
...
[Wed Jun 22 07:36:03.507553 2022] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 2347:tid 139676346078976] [client 78.197.171.129:49212] AH01071: Got error 'PHP message: PHP Warning:  require(/opt/bitnami/wordpress/wp-content/themes/luwix/inc/jetpack.php): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /bitnami/wordpress/wp-content/themes/luwix/functions.php on line 534PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Failed opening required '/opt/bitnami/wordpress/wp-content/themes/luwix/inc/jetpack.php' (include_path='.:/opt/bitnami/php/lib/php') in /bitnami/wordpress/wp-content/themes/luwix/functions.php:534\nStack trace:\n#0 /opt/bitnami/wordpress/wp-settings.php(566): include()\n#1 /bitnami/wordpress/wp-config.php(190): require_once('...')\n#2 /opt/bitnami/wordpress/wp-load.php(50): require_once('...')\n#3 /opt/bitnami/wordpress/wp-admin/admin.php(34): require_once('...')\n#4 /opt/bitnami/wordpress/wp-admin/themes.php(10): require_once('...')\n#5 {main}\n  thrown in /bitnami/wordpress/wp-content/themes/luwix/functions.php on line 534', referer: http://35.237.144.102/wp-admin/themes.php
antoi@wordpress-website-vm:/opt/bitnami/apache/logs$ cd /opt/bitnami/wordpress/wp-content/themes/luwix/inc/
antoi@wordpress-website-vm:/opt/bitnami/wordpress/wp-content/themes/luwix/inc$ ls
back-compat.php     custom-header.php  function.php  icon-functions.php  index.php    template-functions.php  tgm
color-patterns.php  customizer.php     helper        importer            page-header  template-tags.php
antoi@wordpress-website-vm:/opt/bitnami/wordpress/wp-content/themes/luwix/inc$ touch jetpack.php
touch: cannot touch 'jetpack.php': Permission denied
antoi@wordpress-website-vm:/opt/bitnami/wordpress/wp-content/themes/luwix/inc$ sudo !!
sudo touch jetpack.php
antoi@wordpress-website-vm:/opt/bitnami/wordpress/wp-content/themes/luwix/inc$ ls
back-compat.php     custom-header.php  function.php  icon-functions.php  index.php    page-header             template-tags.php
color-patterns.php  customizer.php     helper        importer            jetpack.php  template-functions.php  tgm
antoi@wordpress-website-vm:/opt/bitnami/wordpress/wp-content/themes/luwix/inc$ sudo rm jetpack.php
antoi@wordpress-website-vm:/opt/bitnami/wordpress/wp-content/themes/luwix/inc$ ls
back-compat.php     custom-header.php  function.php  icon-functions.php  index.php    template-functions.php  tgm
color-patterns.php  customizer.php     helper        importer            page-header  template-tags.php
antoi@wordpress-website-vm:/opt/bitnami/wordpress/wp-content/themes/luwix/inc$
```